# How can we programmatically enable/disable default iPhone Camera?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am looking for the way to enable and disable default iPhone camera such as at certain time or latitude/longitude. There are some place where the camera is prohibited, so we can disable it when one reaches at such a place, this is just for an example. Well I thought that disabling and enabling camera in iPhone is not possible. But when my superior gave me the document and said me to check this then I found that its possible to enable/disable default iPhone camera. That document was for enterprise deployment guide, which is associated with enterprise program. There was written the new features of enterprise program and has mentioned
the point of enabling and disabling the default iPhone camera. You can look for the enterprise deployment guide over net and can see that thing. Well I googled for this that how to enable disable the camera, but nothing came. So can you please let me know that how to do this mean enabling disabling camera. Is there any tutorial reference any samples there. Moreover I would like to ask that what is the difference then in enterprise, do we make the apps in the same way in the enterprise as we make for the general developer program.
So how to accomplish this thing enabling/disabling default iPhone camera?
How to implement as well?

well I also thinked same as you are saying that it's not possible. But when I saw the enterprise deployment guide I was shocked.
Here is the link to download this guide and you can have a look over that then you will also come to know that this is possible
[Enterprise Deployment Guide](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sugexp=bvie&xhr=t&q=download+enterprise+deployment+guide&cp=33&pq=how%20can%20we%20programetically%20disable%20the%20default%20iphone%20camera%20to%20work%20at%20certain%20time%20or%20position&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0n&aqi=&aql=&oq=download+enterprise+deployment+gu&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=fed1f7af838ced71&biw=1360&bih=534)

What’s New for the Enterprise in iPhone OS 3.0 and Later
See this para and you can find the point under there where is this mentioned that you can enable/disable camera in iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow use of camera:  When this option is turned off, the camera is completely 
disabled and its icon is removed from the Home screen. Users are unable to take 
photographs.

source:
http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

I believe you can if you have gained the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Thanks for ans.,I have enterprise license.You can read my question as well.Well I didn't find the option to disable and enable camera in this doc..where is this..can you let me know..

Comment: I don't have the doc so I don't sorry but it should be there somewhere. At least you know that it's there :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't disable the camera arbitrarily.  Apple is pretty strict about not letting developers mess with things the user expects to work at all times, and the camera would definitely fall under that category.

So, unless there is some documented, Apple-approved way of doing things, your next best bet is probably jailbreaking and using that to somehow interfere with the camera's operation.  I'm afraid I don't know how you'd go about doing that, however.

As for enterprise use and whatnot, I'm not sure, but I would guess that while an iPhone is part of an enterprise network/group/what-have-you, the admins can disable the camera.  I doubt that is available programmatically either, however, as it doesn't seem like it would be something made available to developers.  So, again, if a method to handle it programmatically isn't mentioned in the documentation you received, it probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @nil well i also thinked same as you are saying that its not possible.But when i saw the enterprise deployment guide i was shocked.
I have updated the link to download that guide you can see that and will then come to know that its possible in iphone to enable/disable camera.Just see the link in my question.

Comment: @Sabby I'm not saying it's impossible for someone to disable the camera, I'm just saying it's probably not something Apple will let you do programmatically.  Again, when it comes to tinkering with core components of the iPhone, Apple has simply not allowed it.  So, at best, administrators of an enterprise group are probably allowed to disable the camera, but there is probably no API for it.

Comment: Well nil thanks for reply.So do you have an idea what could be the solution for that in enterprise.In the core its not allowable,thats why i had written enterprise,do you have any idea how to do that disable/enable camera.

Comment: You should probably try to contact Apple about that.  If you've gotten their blessing to do enterprise work, I imagine you probably have some way of reaching them for support.

Comment: Hi nil,One of my client has enterprise program,would that work or do i need to contact them as well.And is there something different way to work with enterprise.Would then apple provide me information or data to enable/disable the camera.Because there is no info over the net

Comment: I don't know, I don't do enterprise work.  You'd have to contact Apple to know what they'd tell you.  That said, if there is absolutely no info on the net, I would wager that you're not going to get whatever info it is you're hoping to find.

Comment: Nil thanks for the answer that,I also think thats the only option to contact the app store ,after that they will provide some idea or access whatever.Even I dont know about the enterprise more.Well thanks for time.

Comment: @Sabby: Hi Sabby, Have you found any solution for this problem? Were you able to extract these enterprise API?

Comment: @BhanuBirani No, I didn't get the chance to further investigate on this thing